# Does Android Automotive have the same ecosystem as normal Android?

Tags: android, linux, android-automotive

As the title said. Just need to be curious, last time I tried using Snapp Automotive's Android Automotive build for Raspberry Pi and it was able to detect APKs, however, it can't install APKs. Is Android Automotive based on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Android Automotive (AAOS) is Android. e.g. Volvo uses Android and Google services for their cars. PTAL https://developer.volvocars.com/android-automotive/ link for more detail for Volvo cars. Renault also announced EV car with Android Automotive. See https://9to5google.com/2021/09/06/android-automotive-renault-megane-e-tech-electric/